# XAMPP on Windows - Permission Problems?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, windows-vista, xampp

Trying to set up Apache/PHP/MySQL development on my Vista laptop, so I thought XAMPP would be a quick and easy solution.

I have this vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot C:\Development\xxx-projects\xxxx\web
    ServerName miai.local
</VirtualHost>
```

in httpd.conf I am including it

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

but I'm always getting this error when I visit miai.local:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
```

If I set up the virtualhost to read from C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\web instead of my C:\Development\xxx-projects\xxxx\web folder, it works fine.

It's like some kind of permission problem ... only on Windows. And I've no idea how ownership works on windows!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the answer was my virtualhost was bad. Needed a directory, uh ... directive..:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot C:\Development\xxx-projects\xxxx\web
    ServerName miai.local
    <Directory C:\Development\xxx-projects\xxxx\web>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

@furnace: you  might also find it useful to separate the virtual server's logs from the default location:

```
ErrorLog C:\Development\xxx-projects\xxxx\web\logs\error.log
CustomLog C:\Development\xxx-projects\xxxx\web\logs\access.log combined
```

Also, you probably realise this, but you could put the VirtualHost directive directly into httpd.conf rather than including it from a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate called [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), I recollect it worked better for me when I tried setting things up.
There is also a [Portable edition](http://www.pendriveapps.com/uniform-server-wamp-portable-website-server-package/) that works as well.

---

Things that are nearby but do not directly compare with XAMPP/WAMP.

- If you have good bandwidth, there is also the relatively new [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/)!
- I also liked the [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/)